# Extend Keycloak authentication SPI

Tags: keycloak

I would like to implement myself the authentication part of keycloak. This is to be able to add a custom authentication that communicates with another identity server. I saw in keycloak documentation that we have authentication SPI that we can extend but i did not find any tutorials about this. Doc link: [keycloak spi link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html)
I was about to check the keycloak sample provider code for authentication on git hub Ref. [link](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator) however the used version for keycloak was not found when i iported locally the project. Also I cant find the classes under package org.keycloak.authentication in any of keycloak jars (latest ones)

[image: keycloak server spi with no authentication package]

Answer (score 2):

The section *Authenticator SPI Walk Through* of [last release's Server Development guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough) is as good as a tutorial, as far as I can see.

If you want to use the samples against a Keycloak release, you have to select the tag on github that matches your Keycloak release, e.g. tag [4.2.1.Final](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/4.2.1.Final/examples/providers/authenticator) if you are using Keycloak 4.2.1.Final.

The `org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory` class is in `keycloak-server-spi-private` dependency that is used in the pom.xml of the samples. This maven artifact is on Maven Central like the others used in the POM, so the JARs should be retrieved from there by Maven.

Comment: keycloak-server-spi-private in winrar shows an authentication package, but when imported using gradle, i can only see part of the packages and authentication is not part of them. (attached a pic of the classes within).  Gradle dependency:   implementation      group: 'org.keycloak',            name: 'keycloak-server-spi-private',      version: '4.2.1.Final'

Comment: Your screenshot is the wrong one. You are showing  keycloack-server-spi JAR, not **keycloak-server-spi-private** JAR. Check again. I can tell you it is there because I checked on Maven Central. You can get the [JAR from there](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-server-spi-private/4.2.1.Final/) and you'll see the authentication package inside. Btw, Keycloak 4.3.0.Final has just been released :-)